# Calculate the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n+1}{2^\frac{n}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

So, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n+1}{2^\frac{n}{2}}$$

I immediately noticed that $ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ , for $|x|\lt 1$

It reminds of this sum, if we switch nominator and denominator and multiply it by $2^{n/2+1}$, we would get something similar.

Thats all i got so far.

Answer (score 5):

One may start with the standard **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ we get
$$
1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ by making $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, **using $|x|<1$**, gives

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}. \tag3
$$

Now just insert $x:=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$ into $(3)$.

Comment: Great solution, but I have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n+1}{2^\frac{n}{2}}$. As you can see, n goes from 1. But i think, your $(3)$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}$

Comment: You are welcome. Or you may just write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. If you know one of the two sums, then you know the other.

Comment: So i get solution $\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2}-1$?

Comment: @RushThaMan So you get $S=-\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2}+1=-5+4\sqrt{2}$, due to $(-1)^{n-1}$ in the integrand (instead of $(-1)^{n}$).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track thinking about power series.

Note that whenever you see something like $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1) a_n x^n$$ then an anti-derivative is given by $$F(x) = C + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^{n+1}$$ for some constant $C$.

Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} (n+1) x^n$$ has an anti-derivative of the form $$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} x^{n+1} = (-1) x \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n = (-x)\cdot \frac{-x}{1+x}.$$

Finally, the sum you seek is given by $F'(1/\sqrt{2})$

Comment: I get that $F'(x)=-1\frac{-x}{1+x}-x\frac{-1-x}{1+x^2}$. When i plug in $1/\sqrt(2)$ i get something ugly. Am i doing something wrong? And isn't $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^n = \frac{1}{1+x}$

Comment: That would be the correct sum of the series if the index started at zero.

Comment: Also your derivative is incorrect. Use the quotient rule for the second term.

Comment: The correct derivative of $F(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ is $$F'(x) = \frac{2x(1+x) - x^2}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{2x+x^2}{(1+x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}
(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n+1}{2^{n/2}}&=- (n+1)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{n}\\\\
&=-\left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{n+1}\right)\right|_{x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}$$

And the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)x^n$ converges uniformly for $|x|\le r<1$.